# Template function to print C-style array using for_each() AND lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, stl-algorithm

A simple thing. But I spent last one hour and couldn't figure out.

When I compile following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sort.h>
#define array_len(arr) ( sizeof(arr) / sizeof (*arr) )

using namespace std;

template<typename ITER>
void printIt_works(ITER b, ITER e) {
    for_each(b, e, [](int it) { cout << it; } ); // putting int explicitly would work
                                                 // but it's not generic
}

template<typename ITER>
void printIt_doesnt_work(ITER b, ITER e) {
    for_each(b, e, [](ITER it) { cout << *it; } );
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};

    printIt_doesnt_work(a, a+array_len(a)); // how to make this work in a generic way.

    //merge_sort(a, a+array_len(a));
    selection_sort(a, 6);
    insertion_sort_decending(a, 6);
    insertion_sort(a, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation error I get is:

```
In file included from d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/algorithm:63:0,
                 from D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp:4:
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = int*, _Funct = printIt_doesnt_work(ITER, ITER) [with ITER = int*]::<lambda(int*)>]':
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp:17:5:   instantiated from 'void printIt_doesnt_work(ITER, ITER) [with ITER = int*]'
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp:23:42:   instantiated from here
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4185:2: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4185:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'printIt_doesnt_work(ITER, ITER) [with ITER = int*]::<lambda(int*)>'
```

d:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4185 is where `for_each` calls the function passed to it as 3rd param: `__f(*__first);`

I understand the problem, my lambda function is declared to expect `int*` but the template instance of `for_each` calls it with `int`. I just donno how to solve it in a `generic` way.

I can of course work around by making type explicit, but that's not generic:

```
for_each(b, e, [](int it) { cout << it; } );
```

Comment: you need to get reference type from iterator:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/

Comment: don't use that macro to get the array length, use a template<class T, size_t N> size_t al(T(&)[N]){return N; }, since your macro applied to a pointer will compile, but not work as intended.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks. I was actually looking for something like that.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use the new `decltype` keyword to determine the type of what's being iterated over:

```
template<typename ITER>
void printIt_works(ITER b, ITER e) {
    for_each(b, e, [](decltype(*b) it) { cout << it; } );
}
```

This makes a lambda whose argument type is the type of what's being iterated over, which is precisely what you want.

If you don't have `decltype` available on your compiler, you can use the bulkier `iterator_traits` type to do this:

```
template<typename ITER>
void printIt_works(ITER b, ITER e) {
    for_each(b, e, [](typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::reference it) { cout << it; } );
}
```

But that's really ugly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And if they actually do polymorphic lambda's then it'll be: `for_each(b,e,[](auto i){ cout << i; });`

Comment: thanks, i would accept ASA SO allows me to. :)... In the second option, why do we need `typename`? `iterator_traits` defines `typedef T& reference;` so why does `[](std::iterator_traits<ITER>::reference it)` give this error: error: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::reference' is not a type

Comment: @bames53 Thanks. Is that (`auto`) valid syntax or something you wished std would allow? it gives me this error: "error: parameter declared 'auto'"

Comment: @thekashyap : See [What is the template `typename` keyword used for?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)

Comment: @thekashyap it was proposed but not accepted for standardization. People are discussing including it in a future version of C++.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using a lambda function is to use `ostream_iterator`:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Iterator>
void printIt(const Iterator& begin, const Iterator& end) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
  std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(cout));
}
```

Comment: my aim was to learn how to work with arrays, STL algos and iterators, this printing question was more and example. Thanks though. :)